# Getting duplicate rows after two JOINS and a UNION command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables in the following way:

- Client with a client id
- Cards with a card id and a FK with client id
- Transactions with a transaction id and a FK with Card id

Every client can have more than a card, and a card can make more than a transaction.

I want to do the following: Obtain the 3 clients with the minor number of transactions.

My problem: my query returns a client 2 times.

```sql
SELECT TOP 3 
    ClientId, Name, LastName, QtyTrans 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ClientId, Name, LastName, 0 AS QtyTrans 
     FROM 
         Client 
     JOIN 
         Card ON ClientId = IdClient 
     WHERE 
         CardId NOT IN (SELECT CardId FROM Transaction) 
     GROUP BY 
         ClientId, Name, LastName

     UNION

     SELECT 
         ClientId, Name, LastName, COUNT(TransId) AS QtyTrans
     FROM  
         Client 
     JOIN 
         Card c ON ClientId = IdClient 
     JOIN 
         Transaction t ON c.CardId = t.CardId
     GROUP BY 
         ClientId, Name, LastName
    ) TotalTrans 
ORDER BY 
    QtyTrans
```

When the client has transactions with every card, just returns one row, but if one of the cards has no transactions returns one row with the count 0 and another one with the sum of the other cards transactions.

Result:

```
11  Martin  Camejo          0,
7   Matias  Barrenechea 0,
7   Matias  Barrenechea 2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do the following: Obtain the 3 clients with the minor number of transactions.

I don't see what `UNION` has to do with this question.  You just want `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (3) cl.ClientId, cl.Name, cl.LastName,
       COUNT(t.CardId) AS QtyTrans 
FROM Client cl LEFT JOIN
     Card c
     ON cl.ClientId = c.IdClient LEFT JOIN  -- don't know which table has which column
     Transaction t
     ON t.CardId = c.CardId
GROUP BY cl.ClientId, cl.Name, cl.LastName
ORDER BY QtyTrans ASC;
```